# HTML: How to position button at bottom of page before and after page expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to place submit button at the bottom of page which has expandable tables.

If I use `position: absolute` then I can get it at the bottom when the table is not expanded but when I expand the table, the table data goes below the submit button as it won't move with table expansion (due to use of absolute).

If I use `position: relative` then the submit button will not be at the bottom of page when the table is not expanded (due to use of relative).

Is there a way I can have the submit button at the bottom of page in both above cases? I have tried placing `<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button1" />` inside each divs I have and ouside the divs as well. I need those two divs that divide the screen in two vertical sections.

The jsfiddle demo is at [submit button at bottom](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddle300/a3btbagv/14/)
Also the sample code is as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CommDesk Dashboard</title>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btn1").click(function(){
            $(".expand1").toggle();
        });
        $(".btn2").click(function(){
            $(".expand2").toggle();
        });
    })
</script>
<style>
    .expand1 { display: none;
    }
    .expand2 { display: none;
    }

    body {
        background-color: AliceBlue;
    }
    span.note1 {float:left}
    span.note2 {font-size:80%}

    table#t02, #t02 th, #t02 td {
        border: none;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-size:80%;  
    }
    #button1{
        position: absolute;
        bottom:10px;
        left:50%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<div style="float:left; width:50%; background-color: red">

<table id="t02" class="table2">
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>       
    <th style="color:green">Green</th>
    <th style="color:gold", colspan="3">Yellow</th>
    <th></th>
    <th style="color:red">Red</th>    
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="btn1">Post-IVR Call Volume</td>
    <td>&lt</td>        
    <td><input type="text", name="post_ivr_call_volume_good_high", size="2", maxlength="3"></td>
    <td><input type="text", name="post_ivr_call_volume_warning_low", size="2", maxlength="3"></td>
    <td>to</td>
    <td><input type="text", name="post_ivr_call_volume_warning_high", size="2", maxlength="3"></td>
    <td>&gt</td>
    <td><input type="text", name="post_ivr_call_volume_critical_low", size="2", maxlength="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" class="expand1" colspan="8">States</td></tr><tr>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="btn2">IVR Call Volume</td>
    <td>&lt</td>        
    <td><input type="text", name="ivr_call_volume_good_high", size="2", maxlength="3"></td>
    <td><input type="text", name="ivr_call_volume_warning_low", size="2", maxlength="3"></td>
    <td>to</td>
    <td><input type="text", name="ivr_call_volume_warning_high", size="2", maxlength="3"></td>
    <td>&gt</td>
    <td><input type="text", name="ivr_call_volume_critical_low", size="2", maxlength="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" class="expand2" colspan="8">States</td></tr><tr>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button1" />
    <div style="float:left; width:50%; background-color: yellow">Place Holder</div>    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: kind of like this? https://jsfiddle.net/sgnl/a3btbagv/15/

Comment: Try using `position: fixed; ` with your button

Comment: Thanks Sgnl and Sergio Marron for your response. @Sgnl No, I am trying to place button at the bottom of webpage page and not next to table. Something like how we freeze top row of an excel sheet so it always stay at top even if we scroll. Just here I want to freeze botton row of webpage and place submit button there regardless of table being expanded or collapsed. Sergio Marron: using "position: fixed;" is working same as using "position: absolute;". My apologies if I am not  able to express it clearly but trying my best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about pure CSS solution, but here is partial jQuery/partial CSS solution:

1) i've changed your left block display to inline-block, and removed float, so button element can be pushed down, when block is visible...

2) and jquery for changing of position:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn1").click(function() {

    $(".expand1").toggle();
     if ($('.expand1').is(':visible')) {

      $('#button1').css('position', 'relative');

    } else {
      $('#button1').css('position', 'absolute');
    }


  });
  $(".btn2").click(function() {
    $(".expand2").toggle();

    if ($('.expand2').is(':visible')) {

      $('#button1').css('position', 'relative');

    } else {
      $('#button1').css('position', 'absolute');
    }

  });

});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/poj70m4u/

Comment: Thanks a lot nevermind. That's exactly how I wanted it and it's working perfect in jsfiddle. But when I try same from chrome and expand the table rows, the submit button is moving above the second div (Place Holder/yellow) on the right hand side. Trying to figure out if I missed something. I added "height:100vh;" in css, changed the java script and updated div property to have <div style="display:inline-block; width:50%; background-color: red; margin-bottom:20px;">

Comment: Np... well... now i see, i can reproduce it - when you expand both rows, and close first, button position is not ok... it seems that few additional conditions will be needed, OR, maybe additional CSS... Will let you know if i find solution....

Comment: Hm, actually, now i re-tested it, in Chrome too, and works fine, on big screen - yes, keep float:right on the right-hand side div...